# .Net maui: How to reference a color in a binding?

Tags: .net-6.0, maui

So I have a label and I want to set the text colour from a mvvm variable.

VM

```
[ObservableProperty]
private string col = "White";
```

XAML

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}"
       FontSize="20"
       TextColor="{Binding Col}">
```

So in general TextColor="White" works fine

I've tried using the Color object  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/colors

e.g.

```
[ObservableProperty]
private Color col = Colors.White;
```

but I can't get it to work.

I had hoped that a simple string would work...oh for my vain hopes...

Thanks, G.

Edit: I should add that my label is in a CollectionView?

BIG EDIT:
IT WORKS for a standalone label
i.e.

```
  [ObservableProperty]
  private Color col = Colors.White;
```

So the issue is if the label is in a CollectionView. I wonder why?

EDIT: Because the CollectionView is bound to the ItemsSource - doh what a dummy!

Comment: Do other bindings work (e.g. Name)? Have you tried using a regular property instead of an autogenerated one? (I'm trying to rule out the possibility of the ObservablePropertyAttribute not working for you.)

Comment: this works for me: `public Color color { get; set; } = Colors.Purple;`, but `string` did not.  I suspect you would need to use an `IValueConverter` with a string

Comment: Added edit: to question - it worked for a standalone label, but not when inside the CollectionView.

Comment: are you binding to a property on the overall VM, or on the individual item that is bound to the row?

Comment: I am binding to each row in the CollectionView. I will be eventually changing the color of each row based on some condition, but to test I just created a property on the ViewModel as a standalone ObservableProperty - Ahhhhh lightbulb has gone off. The CollectionView is looking for the bound property on the ItemsSource isn't it!!!  Well I have already created a property on my data, but it can only be a string, not Color (I don't think SQLite knows what to do with that, does it. Can I do a convert to a Color object from within the binding i.e. TextColor="{Binding ColorFromString(Col)}"

Comment: Should i close this question and ask a more specific question now?

Comment: Its clear enough - answer is still to use an IvalueConverter from string to color. `{Binding Col, Converter=...}`. Maybe there is one in Community Toolkit.

Comment: Solved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902119/net-maui-is-it-possible-to-convert-a-string-to-a-color-inside-a-binding/72909265#72909265

Answer (score 6):

If you want to bind color(which type is `string`) to your view, you can use [Binding value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to achieve this.

I created a demo to achieve this , you can refer to the following code:

**MyModel.cs**

```
public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }


    string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }

    private string _textColor = "Green";
    public string TextColor
    {
        get { return _textColor; }
        set
        {
            _textColor = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("TextColor");

        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> dataList { get; set; }

    public ICommand ColorChangeCommand { protected set; get; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        dataList = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
        dataList.Add(new MyModel() { Name = "test1", Value = "1" });
        dataList.Add(new MyModel() { Name = "test2", Value = "2" });
        dataList.Add(new MyModel() { Name = "test3", Value = "3" });
        ColorChangeCommand = new Command<MyModel>(async (key) =>
        {
            key.TextColor = "Red";

        });

    }
}
```

**StringToColorConverter.cs**

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = value.ToString();
        switch (color)
        {
            case "Green":
                return Colors.Green;
            case "Red":
                return Colors.Red;
            default:
                return Colors.Yellow;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**A usage:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp0706.Tab1"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp0706" 
             Title="Tab1">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:StringToColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView
             ItemsSource="{Binding dataList}"
             x:Name="mylistview"
             >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Column="0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Converter = {StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Column="1">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Converter = {StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Column="2">
                                <Button Text="change" Command="{Binding BindingContext.ColorChangeCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=mylistview} }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></Button>
                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not to detract from the answer already given, but a couple of points to note for people running into this...

1. "Color col = Colors.White" - Color and Colors aren't the same thing, and within "Color" there is System.Drawing.Color and Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color, so be careful you're not accidentally mixing types.
2. If you do your UI in C# rather than XAML, then you can just bind directly to a Color to begin with and get rid of all the string-converting.

EDIT: I have since written a blog on how to write your UI in C# [Creating MAUI UI's in C#](https://dev.to/smartmanapps/creating-maui-uis-in-c-1adf)