# .Net Maui: Is it possible to convert a string to a color inside a binding?

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-maui

With reference to a previous question [.Net maui: How to reference a color in a binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901517/net-maui-how-to-reference-a-color-in-a-binding)

I have a CollectionView, bound to an ObservableCollection populated from a SQLite databaee.

I want to display each row according to a color string held in the database table

However, I only want to store the colour value as a string.

Is it possible to convert this string to a Color within the binding or call a function to do this?

So for instance:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}"
       TextColor="{Binding ConvertStringToColor(ItemColor)}" />
```

Where ItemColor is a string in my collection model and can be bound to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a class named `ColorTypeConverter` which can be used to convert a string to the color. Such as:

```
ColorTypeConverter converter = new ColorTypeConverter();
Color color = (Color)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString("red"));
```

So you can use the two line codes in a binding's converter or somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, thanks @Liyun Zhang for the pointer which led to the solution.
For the benefit of others here is my solution.

First I created a class StringToColor.cs under a folder called Classes (just my way of doing things).

From the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/data-binding-basics at paragraph Binding value converters and read above and below, though a difficult example to follow.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Converters;
using System.Globalization;

namespace TSDZ2Monitor.Classes;

public class StringToColor : IValueConverter
{

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    ColorTypeConverter converter = new ColorTypeConverter();
    Color color = (Color)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString((string)value));
    return color;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string colorString = "White"; //TODO

    return colorString;
  }
}
```

(The ConvertBack isn't used, just dummy code)

(Most of this was auto created by Visual Studio.)

In my ViewModel I have an ObservableCollection which has a property (field) called ItemColor. This contains a string such as "Yellow" or "Red" etc.

In my page XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TSDZ2Monitor.ViewModels"
             xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:TSDZ2Monitor.Classes"  <---LOOK
             x:Class="TSDZ2Monitor.Pages.BluetoothPage"
             Loaded="ContentPage_Loaded"
             Title="Bluetooth Page">

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <local2:StringToColor x:Key="StringToColor" />
  </ContentPage.Resources>
```

and in the CollectionView, the itemsSource is bound to my ObservableCollection and in the label where I want to display the item in a colour I have

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}"
       TextColor="{Binding ItemColor, Converter={StaticResource StringToColor}, ConverterParameter=AnyStringHere }" />
```

I don't actually need the ConverterParameter as it just appears in the method under the parameter as a string, but I thought it might be useful to show it here.

So now my items can be displayed in any colour I set. It's a faff, but it works.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Updated code to handle null values and set a default return of White. This could be extended further by passing the default colour as the Converter Parameter

Also, you use this directly in your XAML:
`Converter={converters:StringToColourConverter}`
without the need to create a resource thanks to `IMarkupExtension`

```
public class StringToColourConverter : IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ColorTypeConverter converter = new();
        var result = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString((string)value);
        return result ?? Colors.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```