# BackgroundColor="{Binding ...." does not work

Tags: visual-studio, maui

`BackgroundColor="{Binding [item from 'Models']"` does not work

based on sample: 'Shell Mixed Navigation'

when using:
`BackgroundColor="red"` or `"#f2a82f"` --> it works

when using:
`BackgroundColor="{Binding VARHaute.NiveauColor}"` --> Image disappears, no color

In 'Models' :
NiveauColor = `"#f2a82f"`, other items in 'Models' work correctly !)

PS, see github: https://github.com/edikaufmann/RandoGIT
'VARHauteDetailPage.xaml'

? what in the world I'm not seeing ?

Comment: you are trying to bind a string to a Color.  XAML can automatically convert hardcoded strings to the correct type, but the binding mechanism does not.  Either bind to the correct object type, or use an `IValueConverter` in your binding expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Maui: Is it possible to convert a string to a color inside a binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902119/net-maui-is-it-possible-to-convert-a-string-to-a-color-inside-a-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the property of BackgroundColor you will see that it takes a Color parameter.

`public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }`

Your model is trying to feed it a string. So it doesn't understand what it should do with that. Fortunate there is a good way to go about this. We can make a converter where you can manipulate the value before it goes into the property.

```xml
<Image
    BackgroundColor = "{Binding VARHaute.NiveauColor, Converter={StaticResource ColarHexStringToMAUIColorConverter}}"
    HeightRequest = "30"
    HorizontalOptions = "Center"
    Source = "hiking.png"
    WidthRequest = "50" />
```

We have to tell the view where to find resourses so at the top you have to add:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:ColorHexStringToMAUIColorConverter x:Key="ColorHexStringToMAUIColorConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

We make a simple converter like so:

```cs
public class ColorHexStringToMAUIColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string hexColor = (string)value;
        ColorTypeConverter converter = new ColorTypeConverter();

        return (Color)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(hexColor);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The comeplete ContentPage

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Randoff.Views.VARHauteDetailPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Randoff.Converters"
    Title="VAR-Haute">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:ColorHexStringToMAUIColorConverter x:Key="ColorHexStringToMAUIColorConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Margin="0">
            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}"
                Text="{Binding VARHaute.Name}" />
            <!--<Label Text="{Binding VARHaute.Location}"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />-->
            <Image
                HeightRequest="240"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Source="{Binding VARHaute.Image}"
                WidthRequest="300" />
            <Image
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                HeightRequest="100"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Source="{Binding VARHaute.Profil}"
                WidthRequest="200" />
            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Style="{DynamicResource BodyStyle}"
                Text="{Binding VARHaute.Distance, StringFormat='Distance: {0}km'}" />
            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Style="{DynamicResource BodyStyle}"
                Text="{Binding VARHaute.Denivele, StringFormat='Dénivelé: {0}m'}" />
            <Image
                BackgroundColor="red"
                HeightRequest="30"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Source="hiking.png"
                WidthRequest="50" />
            <Image
                BackgroundColor="{Binding VARHaute.NiveauColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorHexStringToMAUIColorConverter}}"
                HeightRequest="30"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Source="hiking.png"
                WidthRequest="50" />

            <Button
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding VARHaute.Map}"
                Text="Map"
                TextColor="White"
                WidthRequest="150" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

The converter in its own file

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Converters;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Randoff.Converters;

public class ColorHexStringToMAUIColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string hexColor = (string)value;
        ColorTypeConverter converter = new ColorTypeConverter();

        return (Color)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(hexColor);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Error XLS0414 
The type 'converters:ColorHexStringToMAUIColorConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Randoff E:\MAUIprojects\RandoGIT\Randoff\Views\VARHauteDetailPage.xaml 9

Comment: well, I'm learning: .. code as comment in https://github.com/edikaufmann/RandoGIT

Comment: You need to add the converter to its own file and usually in its own namespace ie converters. Then add the namespace to the contentpage xaml.

Comment: I have updated the answer with complete code.