# Get value of property other object

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, maui

I have carousel view, I want get property color of next object in carousel using XAML. My XAML:

```
<CarouselView
    HeightRequest="300"
    PeekAreaInsets="100"
    IndicatorView="indicatorView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding TrafficColors}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame HasShadow="False"
                       CornerRadius="5"
                       Padding="0"
                       Margin="10, 0"
                       WidthRequest="200"
                       HeightRequest="300"
                       >
                    <Frame.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="{Binding HEX, StringFormat='#{0}'}" Offset="0.4" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#CFDEF3" Offset="0.77" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Frame.Background>
                    <!--
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:EDocsMainPageViewModel}}, Path=GoToEDoc}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" 
                        />
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    -->
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               FontSize="22"
                               Padding="10"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label Padding="10" Text="{Binding ShiftCode, StringFormat='Номер МЛ:{0}'}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="14" />
                        <Label Padding="10" Text="{Binding RegDate, StringFormat='Дата:{0:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm}'}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="14" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

For example, I want get `BackgroundColor` of next `Frame` in collection. For example, in `HTML` I have object ID or class name and by this keys and JS I can get something. What about XAML, can I set key to objects in collection and from XAML in some way get value by this key? I will be thankful for anything information.

P.S. I don`t want add in view model one more property, I want do that in XAML.

Comment: No, XAML has no way to refer to members of list (collection) views. You will need to do that in c#, in whatever class holds the data that is bound to ItemsSource.

Comment: MessagingCenter Publish/Subscribe might be useful, if the information is not known in the place you need it. Regardless, the solution will be in c#, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, I want get BackgroundColor of next Frame in collection.
> For example, in HTML I have object ID or class name and by this keys
> and JS I can get something. What about XAML, can I set key to objects
> in collection and from XAML in some way get value by this key?

We cannot get the `BackgroundColor` of next `Frame` in collection, since we don't know which item will be selected. But we can get the `currentItem` and `previousItem`.

And we know that the items of the `CarouselView` use the same `DataTemplate` of the `CarouselView.ItemTemplate`, so we cannot get the `BackgroundColor` of next `Frame` by the `x:Name` of the views in the `DataTemplate` layout.

Since you `bind` color to property `Frame.Background`, so you can get the `currentItem` and `previousItem` by event `OnCurrentItemChanged`.

So, I suggest to adding a property (e.g. `BackgroundColor`) to the Item of your `ItemsSource`(`TrafficColors`).

```
  public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
```

Then, you will get the `currentItem` and `previousItem` in event `OnCurrentItemChanged`:

For example:

```
       void OnCurrentItemChanged(object sender, CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
// here you can get the PreviousItem and CurrentItem which include the property `BackgroundColor`
        previousItem = e.PreviousItem as Item;
        currentItem = e.CurrentItem as Item;
        
    }
```

The `TestPage.xaml`

```
 <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                  CurrentItemChanged="OnCurrentItemChanged"
                  PositionChanged="OnPositionChanged">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame HasShadow="True"
                           BorderColor="DarkGray"
                           CornerRadius="5"
                           Margin="20"
                           HeightRequest="300"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           
                           BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor, Converter = {StaticResource ColorConverter}}"
                           >
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                                   HeightRequest="150"
                                   WidthRequest="150"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Location}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Details}"
                                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   MaxLines="5"
                                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
```

For more information about `CarouselView`,you can check: [Configure CarouselView interaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview/interaction?view=net-maui-7.0).

For how to bind color , you can check thread：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901517/net-maui-how-to-reference-a-color-in-a-binding .